# URLFOR($Action.CustomObject__c.New) Not working since Summer 16 release

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, urlfor, summer-16

The  following snippet works well on a sandbox that's still on Spring 16 Lightning Experience but gives the same code gives an error on a sandbox running the Summer 16 release from a visualforce page : `<a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Candidate__c.New, null,null)}" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" >New</a>` .
The following error comes up on the sandbox running the Summer 16 update :

> *Looks like there's a problem.
>   We couldn't find the record you're trying to access. It may have been deleted by another user, or there may have been a system error. Ask your administrator for help.*
>   Does anyone know what could be the cause of this or if there is workaround ?

Comment: It seems like Salesforce is trying to take you to the detail page of a record, rather than the new/edit page.  If you changed your code to `<a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Candidate__c.New, null)}" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" >New</a>` does it work?

Comment: @DougB changing the code to that still does not work

Comment: Well the only thing I can suggest is you open a case with Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this on our Summer '16 sandbox, and it seems to work fine.

```
<a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Custom_Object__c.New)}">Test</a>
```

The nulls can safely be left out on a link like this; give it a try if you haven't already. Hopefully it was just a bug that has been patched since.